# Gradle throws NoClassDefFoundError in base.apk where as classes are available in app-debug.apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

I want to use apache Flink Gradle dependencies on Android, I am struggling with this problem for few days, so basically I have

```
multidex disabled   
g8 enabled 
jacktoolchain disabled
```

In my `dex` file, apache Flink libraries are included as shown below

[image]

but I get the following error when I run my  program

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/flink/streaming/api/environment/StreamExecutionEnvironment;
      at com.example.amar.testing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.amar.testing-ryJ3lLP7oEIkB8lomG6tmA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.amar.testing-ryJ3lLP7oEIkB8lomG6tmA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
      at ja...
```

contents of  app level  `build.gradle` file is

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}


configurations {
    compileOnly
}

android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'

    }

    configurations.all {

        // Enforces Gradle to only compile the version number you state for all dependencies, no matter which version number the dependencies have stated.

        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }


    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {

//        multiDexEnabled true

        applicationId "com.example.amar.testing"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {

        customDebugType {
            debuggable true

        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {

        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


//    dexOptions {
//        preDexLibraries = false
//    }

}

dependencies {
    // not sure if adding compatibility is required here
//    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
//    targetCompatibility = 1.7


    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })


    compileOnly 'org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.11:1.4.0'




    // for multidex
//    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    // for CEP
    //    compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-java', version: '1.4.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'




}
```

contents of  project level  `build.gradle` file is

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {


        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        apply plugin: 'java'
        apply plugin: 'eclipse'
        apply plugin: 'idea'


        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

and code for my main activity is

```
package com.example.amar.testing;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//        MultiDex.install(this);


        try {
            //setting the envrionment variable as StreamExecutionEnvironment
            StreamExecutionEnvironment envrionment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

            envrionment.setParallelism(1);

            DataStream<Event> stream1 = envrionment
                    .addSource(new EventGenerator(10, 10, 1, 1, 100, 200))
                    .name("stream 1")
                    .setParallelism(1);


            envrionment.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String err = e.getMessage();
            Log.d("E", err);

        }

    } //onClick


}
```

Comment: "not able to execute gradle 'compileonly' dependencies as they could not be found by in dex file at runtime" -- the *definition* of `compileOnly` is that they will not be packaged in the APK. Most likely, you should be using `implementation`.

Comment: If you think it's related to your gradle build, you should include this file here.

Comment: @CommonsWare : I get an error when I use `implementation`. I can share the error with you if you say so

Comment: I suggest that you research that error. If you cannot find out how to resolve it, ask a separate Stack Overflow question with the [mcve]. There are few build or runtime errors that are resolved by converting `implementation` to `compileOnly`.

Comment: @tynn : I am wondering why Android is looking for files in `base.apk` whereas it is available in `app-debug.apk`, can you please please tell me how to tackle such kind of error